# How do I solve the "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset" with Borland Database Engine and a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, dataset, bde

The application was working perfectly, until I edited the user database (*.dbf) in OpenOffice.org Calc. Now it gives me the above error about a closed dataset.

Comment: Ehmm... did you try opening the dataset if the operation cannot be performed on a closed dataset?

Comment: How do I open it? I clicked Open in BDE, but nothing changed. The BDE runs on each client computer. The database files are on the server. The program has stopped working on all client computers.

Comment: BDE is the Borland Database Engine; As an engine, it has no interface, hence no "Open" button or menu entry. Where are you clicking Open?

Comment: BDE Administrator. I right-click the dataset and then click Open at the top of the menu.

Comment: I suspect your DBF file was corrupted by OpenOffice. Try with a different copy of the DBF file, and please add this information to the question itself!

Comment: Try rebooting everything, in case something has locked the file. Such as if your openoffice calc program crashed when you closed it, and it's still got the file locked/open.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, I obtained a fresh copy of the dbf file. Everythings works again. It seems OpenOffice damaged the file.

Comment: just for the record, was getting same error when trying to call Refresh on a TListBindSourceAdapter<T>, I needed to set its Active property to true (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.Bind.ObjectScope.TBindSourceAdapter.Active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your own comment, you were unable to open the database file because it was corrupt.  Thus, the error in your case meant not that you forgot to open it, but that your app cannot open the corrupt .dbf file.

Other not-so-obvious reasons why you might get this error, than the obvious thing that you failed to set the table Active property to true, include system or BDE configuration errors (ODBC or ADO, or other BDE runtime files missing or not configured) that are required to open the file

Answer (score 1):

Error message says, that your dataset is not open. 
Seems you forgot to Open it or you Closed it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your application Delphi will restore the `open` or `closed` state that the dataset had in the Delphi form designer.

If there is an error Delphi can quitly drop this and close the dataset.
Also it's possible that you accidently closed the dataset in the designer, after with it no longer auto-opens on ptogram start.
When it's time to use the dataset you will get this error because the dataset is closed.

One option is to explicitly open the dataset in the FormCreate event and add error handling code there, this will allow you to see the error message and debug from there.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    MyDBFTable.Open;
  except on exception e do 
    WriteErrorToLogFile('Cannot open MyDBFTable, error is: ' + e.message);
    // or 
    //ShowMessage('Cannot open MyDBFTable, error is: ' + e.message);
  end; {try}
end;
```

I always do opening of datasets explicitly in FormCreate because this allows me to log any errors. If a client app has an exception it gets emailed to me automatically.

Comment: Apparently the OP is doing it's stuff from the BDE Administrator control panel applet: no dataset Opened or Closed, no Object Inspector.

Comment: @Cosmin, I know I'm just suggesting changing the app so the OP can see errors, or have them written to a log so the error message does not get hidden.

Comment: @Johan: How exactly do you change the code to the `BDE Administrator`, which was written by Borland a decade or more ago and shipped as a binary (executable) file?

Comment: @Ken, not in the BDE, in the Delphi application, The OP told us he wrote a Delphi application.