# Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset: Delphi XE4 error with Firebird 2.5.2

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird, delphi-xe4, firebird2.5

I have following code in Delphi 7 as well as in Delphi XE4. I am migrating my code from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE4. I am dealing with datasets.

My dataset dsABC is declared like following:

```
TfrmMainForm = class(TForm)
  dsABC: TpFIBDataSet;
  ......
  ......
end
```

dsABC is used like following at many places:

```
1. if (dsABC .Locate('ID', Id, [])) then   ---File 1
2. dsABC.Edit ----File 2
```

I mean to say, wherever it is used, its throwing this above said error in Delphi XE4 but same is working fine in Delphi 7.

But if I write following line before using dataset, it works fine

```
if not(dsABC.Active) then dsABC.Active := True;
```

I am forced to write this line in each and every file, and for each and every dataset in Delphi XE4 but I wonder then why its working in Delphi 7. Am I doing right to solve my problem or I need some default setting somewhere to get rid of this problem?

Is dataset in Delphi 7 by default active and inactive in Delphi XE4 and you have to explicitly activate it in Delphi XE4?

I found these links about this problem on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to be relating with my problem:

[How do I solve the "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset" with Borland Database Engine and a Delphi application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774634/how-do-i-solve-the-cannot-perform-this-operation-on-a-closed-dataset-with-borl)

[Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288084/cannot-perform-this-operation-on-a-closed-dataset)

Comment: "Is dataset in Delphi 7 by default active and inactive in Delphi XE4"  Have you tried reading the source?

Comment: @MartynA - I have read the source code. By default it is inactive in the source code and is activated wherever required.

Comment: @Andy_D's answer sounds highly plausible to me.  Anyway, what I would have done before posting here would have included:  1) explicitly opening the dataset in code and 2) setting up an event handler for the dataset's AfterClose event and setting a breakpoint on it.  Then one could see what, if anything is causing the dataset to be closed before its next use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset was getting close because my transaction timeout was set to 1000 i,e one seconds. That's why dataset was getting closed after every second. I set timeout to zero to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Given you've previously posted problems with connecting to the database (which would render any datasets left active at design time inactive) I would say that this is the root of your problem and highlights the problem with relying on datasets being activated in this manner in your code.

Comment: The `Active` property on dataset and connection objects should never get published. It's a pure evil, which only caused problems if you left it in True at design time. I would never ever suggest, or even anyhow notice that you forgot to set `Active` to True at design time.

Comment: @TLama I couldn't agree more. But, the whole RAD thing was largely a marketing thing to compete with VB. "Look! We can have live grids at design-time too!" I personally don't use data access components (I use an object persistence framework) in my applications.

Comment: That makes sense. And it would be even fine, but only if EMBT were implemented a smarter error handling (e.g. "Ignore all other attempts to do the same action for any other components of this type on the form" option) while you're opening a form e.g. with a not existing connection (or when something has changed in a database).

Comment: @TLama - Active property is not set Active at design time anywhere.

Comment: @nkp They won't be because as I already posted in my answer, a failed database connection will automatically render the Active property of any connected datasets to False.

Answer (score 3):

There are some properties in TpFibDatabase for Designsupport:

**DesignDBOptions -> ddoStoreConnected** maybe these are set for delphi7 as default and not in Xe4